# How can I control the viewport without a mouse?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to specify the coordinates of the viewport and direction that the viewport faces without using a mouse or pointing device, in other words, by entering numbers somewhere.

Comment: Do you just want to know how to navigate without a mouse, or do you want to use this for scripting?

Comment: I'm not so interested in writing scripts but if I have to I will. The end result needs to be that I can control the view port in a reasonably "easy" way without a mouse. so if i have to write a script to create a command that allows me to use the viewport without a mouse, then, if that is the only way, that is what i will do

Comment: I still miss the workflow you are aiming at, can you describe the case you would want to do this? _(are you reading values from a file for example that you want to use as a view point?)_ This isn't such a hard thing to do, but mostly users prefer to use the mouse for view-navigation so it was never made a prominent feature.

Comment: @ideasman42 I want to do this in situations where there is no mouse. That could be where the mouse is broken. I don't have a mouse, My device does not allow me to use a mouse etc. In my specific case I am using a tablet. thankfully the tablet provider sold me a keyboard that has a touch pad, effectively turning the tablet into a laptop, but sometimes I like to use the tablet without that keyboard (and touch-pad). so what i really want is a way to use the view-port without a mouse.

Comment: @axrwkr, there are so many areas of blender that need mouse input, Im not sure you can realistically expect to be a proficient Blender user without one, while I'm all for keyboard driven workflows (vim etc), Simple things like selecting a vertex or an object just don't work well via the keyboard.

Comment: @ideasman42 with regards to mouse usage, indeed that is the way that blender is designed, you must have a mouse to use it and your other hand on the keyboard. Blender allows you to control certain things in a very fine tuned way, using a keyboard to enter specific values, rather than trusting the steadiness of the hand and judgement of the eye. In asking this question, I had hoped to find ways to navigate the 3d view without the mouse in a more "controlled" way, this can help in situations where it's uncomfortable or not possible to use a mouse such as when using a tablet or sitting on a train

Comment: I must say that years before I laid hands on a tablet, I wanted to have more specific control of the view port and to be able to type in coordinates to move around to specific places, so, I think it's important recognise that being able to navigate the viewport without a mouse is not so much about using blender ineffectively, but more about having control over it

Comment: ctrl+numpad[2,4,6,8] use for slide 3d viewport &&
hold numpad[2,4,6,8] use for rotate viewport &&
ctrl +[+,-] use for zoom in & out

Answer (score 19):

You won't have fine-tuned control of the viewport without a mouse, but there are extensive options for controlling it via the keyboard:

- You can rotate the viewport using <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, and <kbd>8</kbd>. You can also change between "Perspective" and "Orthographic" views by pressing <kbd>5</kbd>.
- By holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and any of the above, you can pan the view.
- You can press <kbd>/</kbd> to switch between local and global view.
- You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> to roll the view, as of Blender 2.69 (r59707).
- You can centre the view on an object by pressing "<kbd>.</kbd>" on the number pad.
- You can zoom in and out of the view using <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>.
- You can access the current camera view with <kbd>0</kbd>.

> * **Note:** *All of the number commands require that you either use your numberpad or enable "emulate numpad" in the preferences.*

Comment: How do we pan forwards and backwards?

Comment: When I press `.` it just brings up options like "Median Point" and "3D Cursor".

Answer (score 11):

#### 3d Navigation Addon

There is the [3d Navigation Addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/3D_Navigation) which comes bundled with Blender, which I haven't seen mentioned here yet. I made [modifications to this Addon](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/5894868) that make it more convenient for me when I don't have a mouse and numpad connected to this laptop and don't want to mess up my key-bindings to compensate.

It would be easy enough to extend this to include an input area for manual input of the view matrix.

[image]

#### Stored Views Addon

This addon called [Stored Views](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/stored_views) may be of interest to you too. It will let you import and export a list of view orientations and configurations.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried out your modifications as yet, but I had a go at editing the source code for the add-on and hopefully I can use it as a starting point to find a way to type in numbers and drag sliders to control the viewport

Answer (score 5):

By default you can't navigate by entering numeric values, in fact I'm wondering why you would want to do this at all.

## Lock to an object

Since you ask - I would suggest that you use an object.

- Add an empty object
- You may need to press <kbd>N</kbd> to display the [View properties panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#View_Properties_Panel)
- Enable 'Lock to Object' (in the view properties panel)
- Rotate the view to align to this objects axis using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>/<kbd>7</kbd> (numbers on the number pad)

If you want to enter a number, you can using the object location/rotation. Or you can transform the object using numeric input.

---

## [Walk/Fly Mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#walk-fly-mode)

Fly mode allows some keyboard navigation, Once you enter fly mode (Shift+F), you can move the view with WASD,RF keys for up/down. However you can't turn your head using this method, for that part you need the mouse.

---

Note: If you happen to have a file with numbers I think it would be better to write a script that loads the view-ports into camera objects.

Comment: Also, you could make the empty object not visible in the 3D view by turning off its visibility in the Outliner

Comment: **Fly Mode**: when you have the viewport the way you want it, you can press the **enter** key to leave fly mode and keep that view. If you don't like the view press the **escape** key to exit and return to the previous view.

Answer (score 4):

Besides what RolandiXor has listed, if you need better viewport control than what the numberpad provides, you can write a python script/plugin to orient the viewport.

The [`view_matrix`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_release/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_matrix) is what controls the viewport orientation. You could, in theory...

- press the space-bar to bring up [blender's command menu](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Menus)
- select your script/plugin's "Change viewport" command
- then enter the desired view coordinates from the plugin

Though, I doubt you'll be able to do anything else useful in blender without a mouse.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the user preferences with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
2. Change the shortcut in *Input > 3D view > Rotate View* to something like <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>

[image: image for blender help]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) It's preferred to avoid large amounts of text in images for various reasons. I've edited your answer to include short version of the text from your screenshot.

Comment: This isn't right for the question which is asking a way to change the viewport rotation and location without using a mouse. I don't see how your answer changes that.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to rotate the view port on a laptop as if you were using a wheel and track ball on a regular pc.

#### Setup your user settings

Goto *File*>*User Preferences*( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> )

Select With: Right
Check: Emulate 3 Button Mouse
Check: Emulate Numpad
Orbit Style: Turntable

Goto bottom and again select: Turntable.

Save User Settings and close that window.

**The Laptop's Mouse Pad**
Consist of:
The Mouse Pad, Top Left Mouse Button, Top Center Mouse Button,
Top Right Mouse Button, and Bottom Left Mouse Button, and Bottom
Right Mouse Button.

**Learning How to use it**
The first instinct is to press The Top Center Button and then
slide your finger on the pad, it doesn't seem to work that way.

It worked for me when I first slid my finger on the pad and then
pressing on the Top Center Button while sliding your finger on the
pad. You have to slide your finger on the pad at a not-too-slow
rate and at a not-too-fast rate.

Example:
Move your finger in a circular way on the pad, not too fast and
not too slow, keep moving your finger on the pad, then press the
Top Center Button of the Mouse Pad.  You should be able to see
the view tilt around.  If not, release the Top Center Button,
try moving your finger on the pad slower or faster until you find
that magic speed.