# Navigate 3d viewport hovering the mouse (without any button click) with ctrl/alt/shift key combinations

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut, optimization

Is this possible to **navigate in the 3d viewport** just **hovering the mouse** (or the pen on a tablet) **with the existing ctrl/alt/shift** key combinations BUT **without the need to click on any button of the mouse/pen?** Just hovering the cursor on the 3d viewport and with the keyboard.

Comment: You can use [Walk or Fly modes](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#walk-fly-mode) to mavigate without keyboard; however it may be not convenient to stop flying at certain point. See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-can-i-control-the-viewport-without-a-mouse

Comment: Thank you Mr Zak. I would like to use the keyboard and the mouse (hover), but not using the mouse buttons. The same behavior as when using "walk mode" if you hover the mouse you can pan the camera, but I would like also to rotate and zoom the view, using keyboard combinations.

Comment: To rotate the view when in Walk mode use the same as for moving - move the mouse and it will rotate the viewpoint. If you'd like to change this behaviour you can always remap keyboard shortcuts for something else to [move view without mouse buttons](http://imgur.com/8x9tHvL). You'll need remap all the keys responsible for adjacent behaviour.